# Installing make and errors coming while trying to install gr-gsm

Tags: software-installation, compiling

```
git clone https://git.osmocom.org/gr-gsm
cd gr-gsm
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
mkdir $HOME/.grc_gnuradio/ $HOME/.gnuradio/
make
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Radio Software Radio Toolkit (*gnuradio*) is in the default repositories for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, however gr-gsm is in the default repositories for Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 only. To install gnuradio and gr-gsm in Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnuradio gr-gsm
```

Search for the relevant libgnuradio-runtime version with `apt search libgnuradio-runtime` and install it with `sudo apt install libgnuradio-runtime*` .